# PayPal JavaScript SDK client side JS, how works fetch function?

Tags: javascript, php, paypal

Question is related to PayPal JavaScript SDK client side JS
https://developer.paypal.com/docs/checkout/reference/server-integration/capture-transaction/#on-the-server .
How works `fetch` function?

According official documentation, the client side is similar to:

```
paypal.Buttons({

createOrder: function(data, actions) {
  return actions.order.create({
    purchase_units: [{
      amount: {
        value: '0.01'
      }
    }]
  });  
},

onApprove: function( data, actions ) {
    return actions.order.capture().then( function(details) {
        //alert('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name);
        // Call your server to save the transaction
        //console.log('Transaction completed' ); alert(details); 
        console.log( 'data.orderID = ' + data.orderID ); 
        document.getElementById('orderID').value = data.orderID;
        console.log('data'); console.log(data); 
        console.log('Transaction completed by ' + details.payer.name.given_name );
        //return fetch('/paypal-transaction-complete', {
        return fetch( 'https://domain.biz/pay/ppal_1025/EN/pay', {
            method: 'POST',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                orderID: data.orderID,
                submitPpal: 1 //imitation of submit button
            })
        }); // return fetch( 'https://typejoy.biz/pay/ppal_1025/EN/pay
    }); // return actions.order.capture().then( function(details
} // onApprove: function(data, actions

  }).render('#payPp');
```

I do not understand how works :

`return fetch( 'https://domain.biz/pay/ppal_1025/EN/pay', { <... > } )`

I do not see any POST results in files related to url  `https://domain.biz/pay/ppal_1025/EN/pay`

Empty POST is logged to `out.php` for url `https://domain.biz/pay/ppal_1025/EN/pay`

```
file_put_contents( __DIR__'/out.php', json_encode( $_POST ) .' from '.__FILE__  );
```

PayBundle\Resources\actions\ppal\action.php

```
echo "<br> POST ="; print_r($_POST);  
file_put_contents( PHP_EOL. PHP_EOL. __DIR__ .'/out.php', json_encode( $_POST ) .' from '.__FILE__ , FILE_APPEND );
```

Comment: THE ANSWER IS HERE : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049164/paypal-javascript-sdk-client-side-does-not-post-to-server/55052269#55052269

Comment: Does this answer your question? [PayPal JavaScript SDK client side does not post to server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55049164/paypal-javascript-sdk-client-side-does-not-post-to-server)

Comment: I've put a solution and explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/60500006/386405